# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '98)' at line 1

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

My JDBC code is:

```
String name=req.getParameter("name");
String regno=req.getParameter("regno");
String m1=req.getParameter("m1");
String m2=req.getParameter("m2");
String m3=req.getParameter("m3");

Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
stmt.execute("create table students(sname varchar(20),regno varchar(10),mark1 int,mark2 int,mark3 int)");
stmt.execute("insert into students values('"+name+"','"+regno+"',"+m1+","+m2+","+","+m3+")");
```

I get the below error after I execute above code.

> java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '98)' at line 1

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You build the INSERT statement dynamically, and in that statement you have

```
m2+","+","+m3
```

So if `m2==1` and `m3==2` this generates

```
1,,2
```

Which makes the SQL syntax invalid.  You need to be using a parameterized query with a prepared statement instead, as in

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into students values(?,?,?,?,?)");
ps.setString(1,name);
ps.setString(2,regno);
ps.setInt(3,m1);
ps.setInt(4,m1);
ps.setInt(5,m3);
int nupdate = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Currently the values of `m1`, `m2` and `m3` are `String`s in the code but `int` in the database.  You should convert their values to `int` for use with the `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra comma `","+","`

This error is in the line with `insert` statement.

```
 stmt.execute("insert into students values('"+name+"','"+regno+"',"+m1+","+m2+","+","+m3+")");
```

Let's assume your values are as follows

```
 name = x
 regno = 2
 m1 = 33
 m2 = 45
 m3 = 48
```

Then, the SQL insert statement created by your program (string concatenation) will be

```
 insert into students values('x','2',33,45,,48);
```

The above statement is wrong and has an extra comma before `48`

Remove the extra `+","` block in the insert statement line and you can make this right.